# Is "Fantasia" a classical Latin word? What was its original meaning?

Tags: vocabulary, meaning

I'm indecisive as to what title to chose for a novel I finished writing. I went for a pseudo-Latin title : "Apex Fantasia" as it is a fantasy novel.
But I still wonder if I can find alternatives that sound more right, and I'm not sure of the meaning of "Fantasia" or even if it is a real classical Latin word to begin with.

Comment: I think your question would be helped by explaining what the title is supposed to mean!

Answer (score 8):

*Fantasia* is Italian, not Latin, though you happen to be in luck, for the Latin is spelled [*phantasia*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dphantasia), and it has two distinct meanings:

> I.**an idea, notion, fancy** (post-Aug.): “Nicetas longe disertius hanc phantasiam movit,” Sen. Suas. 2, 15: “cor tuum phantasias patitur,” Vulg. Ecclus. 34, 6.—As a term of reproach: phantasia, non homo, a mere notion or fancy, the mere semblance of a man, Petr. 38 fin. (in Cic. Ac. 1, 11, 40; 2, 6, 8 al., written as Greek, and translated visum).—
> II. **A phantom, apparition**: “(animus) colligit visa nocturna, quas phantasias nos adpellamus,” Amm. 14, 11, 18.

Unlike in English, *apex* is not an adjective (apex predator, for example, is non-sense in Latin). I don't know what you're *trying* to say with that title, but it's not grammatical as it stands. Other potential options include *summus*, *primus*, or *optimus*, depending on what nuances you're trying to get across.

Comment: Though, I wouldn't be surprised to see _fantasia_ as a variant spelling (albeit probably post-Classical).

Comment: It might be worth stating explicitly something hidden in the L&S entry: *phantasia* (along with *phantasma*) is a loan-word from Greek, and has [very few, post-Augustinian citations](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23phantasi). The Cicero citation is of the *Greek* word, in fact, and is translated *into* Latin.

Comment: @brianpck Check the TLL, which lists many more sources! [Have to run, will expand on this later.]